# Can't use custom css when use antd design in react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

I setup SSR for my project. When run webpack, It's just compile antd design.

All css files that I import into the component has gone.

[webpack.client.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98lFA.png)

**import css to component in react**

```
import './styles/styles.css';
```

Please help me!

Comment: Please refer this link before asking question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask